# Send json using jackson and spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I need to send a json to a web address where this json will be consumed, basically I have a list of Dto's that I need to turn into a Json (with jackson).
Some information must be passed in the header:
timestamp= time, key= blablabla, accesskey= bla bla bla
As I have no experience with spring, i need to know how to do the HTTP request using Spring boot
(is it a post?)

Here's what I've implemented so far:

Student Dto Class

```
  public class StudentDto {

    private String name;
    private String RM;
    private String RG;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRM() {
        return RM;
    }

    public void setRM(String RM) {
        this.RM = RM;
    }

    public String getRG() {
        return RG;
    }

    public void setRG(String RG) {
        this.RG = RG;
    }
}
```

Turning my list of students into json

```
    public String convertToJson(List obj) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
        return jsonInString;
    }
}
```

And this is the format json has to leave

```
{
"table": "student",
"rows":
[
    {
        "PersonID": 1,
        "name": "Name",
        "RM": "56656565",
        "RG": "8787845-7",
    },
{
        "PersonID": 2,
        "name": "Name",
        "RM": "56656565",
        "RG": "8787845-7"   
    }
]
}
```

Comment: who ever owns the service you're sending the request to will have what Type of request you need GET/POST/PUT. better would probably be to use a RestTemplate and not have to make the json yourself

Comment: I need to send a post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is and example of how to use rest template. You'll want to create a class for the request that has `String table;` and `List<StudentDto> rows;` as members

```
private static void createEmployee()
{
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employees";
    MultiValueMap<String> headers = new MultiValueMap<>();
    //set headers
    HttpEntity<EmployeeVO> newEmployee = new HttpEntity<>(new EmployeeVO(-1, "Adam", "Gilly", "test@email.com"),headers);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    EmployeeVO result = restTemplate.postForObject( uri, newEmployee, EmployeeVO.class);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*edit added headers

*edid [look here for json formatting](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations)

you will also need to have the id field added to your object

Comment: thanks, but what about json and the json header how do I do it?

Comment: json is handled by the template. if you need some custom serialization you just annotate the object. if you need a field named a certain way or a date in a particular format.